# Need help creating a MySQL view, complex joins

Tags: mysql, join, view, joomla

So, in joomla there are several tables:

```
1) users - uid, username, email
2) groups - gid, title
3) user_group_map - uid, gid
```

So, what I am wanting to do is create a view which makes it easier for me to write SQL to find users that are in some groups but not others.

So, what I was thinking was creating a view which pulls the uid, username, email from the user  table and has a bool field for each group title which is whether there is an entry for that uid/gid in the user_group_map table.

Make sense?

Comment: Why would you need a `VIEW` for this when a simple query would suffice? Views need to be ripped out and replaced each time your query logic changes which means less flexibility than doing the query directly.

Comment: I am open to a suggestion on the simple query you have in mind, turn it into a view is just syntactic sugar really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can make this this way

```
SELECT uid, username, email, CASE WHEN IFNULL(ug.uid,0)=0 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_group_map  ug
ON ug.uid = u.uid, groups g
```

It will look to something like that, if the user is in the group it will return 1.

Comment: I think you might be on the right track, but isnull takes two arguments?

Comment: @RedBullet you are right. source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I think this got me part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that assumes that you have two variables "$inlist" and "$notinlist".

```
select u.*
from user_group_map ug join
     users u
     on u.uid = ug.uid join
     groups g
     on ug.gid = g.gid
group by u.uid
having sum(case when $inlist like concat('%', g.title, '%') then 1 else 0 end) =
           length($inlist) - length(replace($inlist, ',', '') and
       sum(case when $notinlist like concat('%', g.title, '%') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This assumes that none of the groups have a comma in its name.

I haven't tested this SQL, so it might have syntax errors.

Comment: What are the $inlist and $notinlist variables exactly?

Comment: @RedBullet . . . They are lists of ids to be included or excluded.

Comment: oh I see. I was thinking that I wanted a flattened table out of this so that I could formulate more regular queries like: select * from MyUsers where SuperUser = '1';